# multicolumn with vertical line in array/tabular

Tags: arrays, alignment, line, nicematrix, vertical

I would like to write equations like this:

[image]

But with all the "x=" left aligned after the word "Soit" (meaning "either" in english). Here I used the following code with the `\phantom{}` command, which is far not the best and doesn't align exactly the "x=":

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
   \[
   \begin{array}{l|l}
       3x^4=48 \quad   &\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}\\
       x^4=16  &\\
       \mbox{Soit } x=\sqrt[4]{16} &\\
       \phantom{Soitt} x=2 &\in\mathcal{D}_x\\
       \mbox{Soit } x=-\sqrt[4]{16} &\\
       \phantom{Soitt } x=-2 &\in\mathcal{D}_x\\
   \end{array}
   \]  
\end{document}
```

I also tried the `\multicolumn` command, but then the vertical line after the `\multicolumn` command is shifted to the left, and it gives this:

[image]

with the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{array}{ll|l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{3x^4=48} \quad  &\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{x^4=16} &\\
        \mbox{Soit } &x=\sqrt[4]{16} &\\
        &x=2    &\in\mathcal{D}_x\\
        \mbox{Soit } &x=-\sqrt[4]{16} &\\
        &x=-2 &\in\mathcal{D}_x\\
    \end{array}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  your (particular) case you can use simple `array`, and top and bottom `aligned` math environments:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.50cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{l|l}
\begin{aligned}[t]
3x^4 & = 48     \\
 x^4 & = 16 
 \end{aligned}  & \cdot\frac{1}{3}                           \\
 \begin{aligned}[b]
\mbox{Soit}\quad    x & = \sqrt[4]{16}      \\  
                  & = 2
\end{aligned}   & \in \mathcal{D}_x     \\
 \begin{aligned}[b]
\mbox{Soit}\quad   x & = -\sqrt[4]{16}    \\
                  & =- 2
\end{aligned}   & \in \mathcal{D}_x     \\
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's the solution based on `array`. In order to achieve the effect beginning from the 3rd row, you can make "Soit" be a part of the first column and remove space it would normally occupy to avoid pushing the first `=` towards the right; this is done by `\rlap{}`. See the example:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{r @{\;}c@{\;} r @{\;}c@{\;} l|l}
                                          3x^4 &=& 48 & &            & \displaystyle \frac{1}{3} \\
                                           x^4 &=& 16 & &            & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{Soit}} & &  x &=& \sqrt[4]{16}  & \\
                                               & &  x &=& 2          & \in \mathcal{D}_x \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\rlap{Soit}} & &  x &=& -\sqrt[4]{16} & \\
                                               & &  x &=& -2         & \in \mathcal{D}_x
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is another variant with the equals signs aligned.

[image: a]

I used the `nicematrix` package with the `cell-space-limits=4pt` option to vertically expand the cells.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nicematrix}% added <<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=4pt}% expand the cells vertically  
\setlength{\arraycolsep }{3pt}% control the columns separation


$\begin{NiceArray}{rcc|@{\;}cl}
3x^4            &=& 48              & &  \displaystyle \frac{1}{3} \\
x^4             &=& 16              & &                     \\
\text{Soit}\ x  &=& \sqrt[4]{16}    & &                     \\
x               &=& 2               & &  \in \mathcal{D}_x  \\
\text{Soit}\ x  &=& -\sqrt[4]{16}   & &                     \\
x               &=& -2              & &  \in \mathcal{D}_x  \\
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** **Or** with the first two equation left aligned  and without additional packages:

[image: c]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
  
    \setlength{\arraycolsep }{3pt}% control the columns separation  
    
    $\begin{array}{lcl|@{\;}cl}
        3x^4 =48        &   &                   & &  \cdot\displaystyle \frac{1}{3} \\
        x^4  =16        &   &                   & &                     \\
        \text{Soit}     &x =& \sqrt[4]{16}      & &                     \\
                        &x =& 2                 & &  \in \mathcal{D}_x  \\
        \text{Soit}     &x =& -\sqrt[4]{16}     & &                     \\
                        &x =& -2                & &  \in \mathcal{D}_x  \\
    \end{array}$
    
\end{document}
```

Finally, using your setup, to get the vertical line right  add another column. Try this code:

```
\[
\begin{array}{lll|l}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{3x^4=48}                     &   &\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{x^4=16}                      &   &               \\
    \mbox{Soit }                &x=\sqrt[4]{16}     &   &                   \\
                                &x=2                &   &\in\mathcal{D}_x\\
    \mbox{Soit }                &x=-\sqrt[4]{16}    &   &\\
                                &x=-2               &   &\in\mathcal{D}_x\\
\end{array}
\]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Still, these solutions seem rather complicated to me... Is there no way to simply use ```\multicolumn``` and that the vertical lines are aligned? This would be for me the easiest... Beside, I would prefer to have the 2 first equations left aligned.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I expected! So again, thank you for your time and attention!